# How to show multiple images inside one view with different image height and width?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview, cardview

How to show multiple images inside one view with different image height and width like collage view in android xml layout

[image]

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to achieve this, using either RelativeLayout, LinearLayout, ConstraintLayout or others as the parent view.

Here's an example using LinearLayout (you'll need to substitute the `android:src:"...."` references to match your drawable file names, and you might like to tweak the margins):

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/view_profile_cd"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_profile_picture_placeholder" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/medium_border"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/content_desc"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_a_photo"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/content_desc"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_a_photo"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/content_desc"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_a_photo"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/content_desc"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_a_photo"/>

     </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Resulting in:

[image]